# Wrong filenames after unzipping on ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, encoding, unzip, winrar

## Problem

I have a zip-file that I would like to unzip on Ubuntu with the correct filenames (they contain æ,ø,å).

What I have tried:

## 1. Unrar in Windows 10 - WORKS!

Everything works as expected and filenames are correct.

## 2. Unzip in Ubuntu

```
unzip file.zip
```

The characters æ,ø and å are missing from the filenames, where 'æ' has been replaces with 'C'.

I attempt to detect the encoding of the zip-file, but it doesn't seem to tell me anything.

```
file file.zip
```

## 3. Unzip with encoding in Ubuntu

I attempt to unpack the file using various encodings that are often used for æ,ø,å-containing texts.

```
unzip -O UTF-8 file.zip
unzip -O ISO-8859-1 file.zip
unzip -O windows-1257 file.zip
```

None work...

## 4. Unzip using 7zip in Ubuntu

It is suggested that 7zip may fix the problem, but no..

```
7z x file.zip
```

## 5. Unzip using 7zip and danish language setting in Ubuntu

It is suggested that I change the ubuntu language settings and then try again.

```
saveLang=$LANG
export LANG=da_DK
7z x file.zip
export LANG=$saveLang
```

This also does not work.

## 6. Unzip using Python3 in Ubuntu - WORKS!

The unzip works correctly if I use Python3 for the purpose, but there must be an easier way?

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip', "r") as z:
  z.extractall("/home/xxxx/")
```

## 7. Next step

I am considering finding a list of "ALL" encodings, and then just extracting the filenames and going through them manually. Something along the line of this...

```
while read p; do
  echo "$p"
  unzip -j -O $p file.zip
done <encodings.txt
```

## Conclusion

Windows and Python3 seems to have some MAGIC under the hood that I cannot replicate. Do you guys have any suggestions to what this "MAGIC" is?

- How do I identify the encoding of the filenames of a zip-file?
- Where can I get a list of all encodings for step 7.
- Is there any easy way to solve this problem without having to write e.g. a python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key piece of information you provided was that `unrar` on windows was able to create the filenames correctly. So unless `unrar` is doing some encoding detection under the hood, that meant that there is a good chance that the encoding used in the zip files matches the default codepage used on your Windows setup.

Using `chcp` on Windows you see that your codepage is

```
Active code page: 850
```

It's then a simple matter of telling `unzip` that the encoding used in the zip file is `CP850`

```
unzip -O CP850 file.zip
```

Comment: If you can't see what codepage was (for example if it wasn't you who chreated the arcive), you can just try them all: CP1251, CP850, CP866, CP855 ... [more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)